# Without a backup, can I downgrade from Sierra to El Capitan?

Tags: mac, macos, downgrade

I haven't been making backups on my laptop (I know, this is something I'm going to change!) but I really want rid of Sierra, it's mucking about my wifi connectivity loads and I'm sick of it restoring Mac apps to the Dock that I just don't want there.

All the solutions I've seen so far to downgrade rely on having backups of your machine from a time where it was on El Capitan - which I don't have!

How/can I do this without having backups?

Comment: This is how much fun I had doing the same thing - **with** backups, but just not the right backup - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271104/revert-to-el-capitan Without a backup it's a pure nuke & pave operation.

Answer (score 2):

If you downloaded El Capitan Installer in Mac App Store before, you can find the application in your Purchased section on the top of the app, where you can download it again, write the installer to a usb and boot from that USB in order to install El Capitan to your Machine. Details are written [here](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-downgrade-from-macos-sierra-el-capitan-remove-macos-sierra-3581872/).

Comment: I tried re-downloading El Cap already, but when it completed a popup came saying it couldn't be used as a higher OS is now in use. How do I find where it downloaded to (it's not in my regular downloads folder)?

Comment: Find an usb drive and paste this command to the Terminal `sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app`