# Building boot caches on boot helper partition failed

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, startup, recovery

Due to a Hard Drive failure I have had to restore my mac from a backup. Following the **Restore From Time Machine Backup** procedure under recovery mode takes about 8 hours. Eventually the data is restored on the new hard drive, but the drive won't boot. It gets stuck at around 50% of the boot process with the apple logo.

I have tried the **Reinstall macOS** procedure under recovery mode, but at the end it prompts the message:

> **OS X could not be installed on your computer**
>
> Building boot caches on boot helper partition failed. Quit the installer to restart your computer

This happens for both Mavericks as for Sierra.

What can I do to fix this problem? After several, very long attempts, I am desperate to get my data and mac back.

[image]

Comment: Please boot to Recovery Mode, open Terminal in the menubar > Utilities and enter `diskutil list` and `gpt -r show disk0`. Take a pic of the results and add it to your question.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed my problem. Before the crash of my hard drive, I was using Yosemite as OS. Apparently you cannot restore a backup made in Yosemite with a bootable USB of either Mavericks or Sierra or with the network restore of Lion.

I eventually made a bootable USB drive of Yosemite and reinstalled a new copy of Yosemite on my new HDD. After installation I used the **Migration Assistant** to retrieve my data. This took several hours, but afterwards I could normally reboot my computer. I had tried this same procedure with Lion, Mavericks and Sierra, but that didn't work and the computer wouldn't boot.

So if you find yourself having to restore a time machine backup, use a bootable macOS of the same macOS version you were running.

Comment: I knew you couldn't go 'downhill', didn't know you can't go 'uphill' either. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271104/revert-to-el-capitan for some of the fun things you can do trying to go downhill ;)

Answer (score 0):

[bigger picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JehI.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JehI.jpg)K I did what you said. Here is my picture.
What next  [picture attached of what you asked for after typing in terminal here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zML2.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zML2.jpg)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/341766)