# Beta to regular

Tags: macos, high-sierra, beta

I need some advice. I have my Macbook running MacOS High Sierra Version 10.13 Beta. I'd like to downgrade to MacOS Sierra, can someone please help me with resources, a link, or anything similar?

Comment: App Store, Purchase History. Download, clean install. There's no going back from Time Machine etc. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271104/revert-to-el-capitan for what happens when trying to go 'downhill' even with good backups.

Comment: I suppose I ought to push this into an answer, as even with the caveats, it's really the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no simple 'Revert' option. You cannot go 'downhill' even using Time Machine, unless you swapped out your Time Machine drive right before the update - it simply won't let you.

Your only option is from the App Store, using your Purchase History to find the previous OS installer; download, make a bootable USB key & start afresh from there. iCloud ought to be able to sync, & you will be able to use Time Machine to pull some data back, but it will not be seamless.

As a cautionary tale, I'll link to my trials & tribulations trying to revert from Sierra to El Capitan, which even with multiple backups wasn't painless - [Revert to El Capitan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271104/revert-to-el-capitan)