# I'm using OSX 10.11 what should I be aware of when installing 10.12

Tags: macos

I'm a developer, and I'd rather not mess up anything on my system. So I guess, the general. Take a backup advice applies.

But is there anything else in particular that I should be aware of? Something that have gone wrong for users in the past?

The wonkyness of apple software has been quite a lot in the news as of late... so that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from one major revision to the next, there could be a lot of things if you are a developer (which I am not).

The *smart* thing to do is to make a full **bootable** backup of your boot drive (CCC and Super Duper to name a couple I am familiar with). Then TEST the backup by booting from it. Then unplug it from the Mac and put the backup drive in another room.

Do your upgrade and then check your environment, your builds, your tools and make sure everything is working as expected.

Now if things get messed up all you have to do is boot from your backup drive, wipe the internal (boot) drive. *Remembering to save any changes to files you made in the interim to your backup drive.* And clone the backup back to your original boot drive.

With any luck you'll only kill a half day or so...

Comment: & see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271104/revert-to-el-capitan for what can happen if you wait too long before you decide to revert :/

Answer (score 0):

Check all of your third party apps to see if they support 10.12. There's not much difference between 10.12 and 10.11, so I don't think you'll run into much trouble, aside from apps not supporting 10.12 if they are older, and of course 10.12 not supporting many older (and some not so old) Macs.