# Trying to downgrade to High Sierra but Time Machine restore upgrades back to Mojave

Tags: time-machine, restore, mojave

I've been having major issues with Mojave - slow-downs, connectivity issues, crashing - you name it. I tried to downgrade back to High Sierra.

High Sierra gets installed fresh, but my Time Machine backup was made on Mojave.

When I hit restore, all the sudden I have Mojave again.  NO!

Is there a way to have my files back without MacOS automatically upgrading me back to Mojave?

Answer (score 3):

You can only do a file restore, individual files/folders rather than a full disk restore.

Once Time Machine has been used on a newer OS, it will not allow you to go back.

Related - [Revert to El Capitan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271104/revert-to-el-capitan)
& also covered briefly in [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos)