# MacOS downgrade. Restore Time Machine backup on older OS

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, restore

I've been surprisingly stupid to believe Apple that MacOS Ventura is a worthy upgrade and **didn't make a Time Machine copy** prior to upgrade. Now I'm amazed by how Apple screwed up my previously perfect M1 Macbook. It even got hotter by 5 degrees on idle, and reaches 70 while simply watching video in Telegram.

Now I simply want to go back to Monterey. As I have many custom setting and tweaks in the system, I really don't want to loose it. **Is there a way to restore Ventura backup to Monterey system?**

Comment: No. It will simply refuse. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271104/revert-to-el-capitan - I can no longer remember exactly how I tested the Migration… but it got me nowhere.

Comment: If your experience is not universal, or not observed in a large number of cases, then it's likely that the OS is not a direct cause. Test the behaviour in Safe Boot mode; in a new user account; and make sure that all software is updated to versions that are compatible with Ventura. Make sure you haven't got any old background processes running automatically that might be causing issues. However: the M1 can get up to 100˚C before throttling starts, so 70˚C doesn't sound like a problem. Also, make sure you're using Telegram for Mac, not Telegram Desktop.

Comment: Also: is it possible that your 'custom tweaks' might be to blame? Do you have any Fan management apps running? (If so, turn them off.)