# Does restoring from Time Machine revert also the OS?

Tags: time-machine, downgrade

I want to try updating my MacBook Pro 13" (2013) from Mavericks to Sierra but I am afraid of performance issues. So I would like to be able to downgrade easily if I like.

Does a Time Machine backup allow to do this? I think that if this is the case I would have to restore the backup from the Recovery Mode, right?

Thank you

Comment: I found an answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/265948/restore-mavericks-from-time-machine?rq=1

Comment: Make sure to remove the Time Machine volume before you upgrade, or you cannot use it to go back. See this for a list of trials & tribulations trying to do similar - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271104/revert-to-el-capitan

Answer (score 1):

I just attempted to do this with a 2013 air, Trying to use a Mojave Time machine backup after installing big-sur. It downgraded to Mojave.... bummer

Comment: Thanks for sharing, weird that it seems in contrast with the comment under my question, in which one answers says that Time Machine doesn't hold OS information. Maybe it depends on the OS